# Build errors with custom recipe

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake, meta-raspberrypi

As I am new to yocto, I've been trying to make a recipe from simple C program which uses makefile to generate the binary. After creating the recipe I am getting the following error

```
Command '['aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy', '--only-keep-debug', '/home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/myshell/0.1-r0/package/usr/bin/hello_shell', '/home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/myshell/0.1-r0/package/usr/bin/.debug/hello_shell']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Subprocess output:aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/myshell/0.1-r0/package/usr/bin/hello_shell'

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/myshell/0.1-r0/temp/log.do_package.15925
ERROR: Task (/home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/meta-shell/recipes-myshell/myshell/myshell_0.1.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

Here is my recipe

```
SUMMARY = "bitbake-layers recipe"
DESCRIPTION = "Recipe created by bitbake-layers"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=6e0eb429dbab531d0874038360a879b9"

SRCREV = "ce92f43aea4f5ea32858892f446084ea9f2b2a7f"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/bhargavthriler/simple_shell.git"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/"  

do_compile() {
    make
}

TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 hello_shell ${D}${bindir}
}
```

And here is my makefile

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)

CC = gcc

OBJ_NAME = hello_shell

all : ${SRCS}
    $(CC) $(SRCS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)

clean :
    rm $(OBJ_NAME)
```

I am facing build errors. I am buiding it with the meta-raspberrypi
My complete build

```
bhargav@bhargav-Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~/RPI3/Build/poky/build (master)$ bitbake rpi-basic-image
Loading cache: 100% |########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 2876 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 cortexa53 crc"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "master:2e11d97b6c95e89aa1f9d3603a966c94c442469e"
meta-raspberrypi     = "master:27d0016b6b7634ea2abf26a06b1ab8071fbdb0d5"
meta-oe              = "master:679bb4912613f3860e8527557602251e5e5f2c41"
meta-python2         = "master:2684086f91e7074324081196c8a5f9945d39650e"
meta-shell           = "master:81fd3448f603a56409389247443439cad4fdaa67"

Initialising tasks: 100% |###################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:02
Sstate summary: Wanted 111 Found 111 Missed 0 Current 1304 (100% match, 100% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3725 tasks of which 3725 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
bhargav@bhargav-Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~/RPI3/Build/poky/build (master)$ bitbake myshell
Loading cache: 100% |########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 2876 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 cortexa53 crc"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "master:2e11d97b6c95e89aa1f9d3603a966c94c442469e"
meta-raspberrypi     = "master:27d0016b6b7634ea2abf26a06b1ab8071fbdb0d5"
meta-oe              = "master:679bb4912613f3860e8527557602251e5e5f2c41"
meta-python2         = "master:2684086f91e7074324081196c8a5f9945d39650e"
meta-shell           = "master:81fd3448f603a56409389247443439cad4fdaa67"

Initialising tasks: 100% |###################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Sstate summary: Wanted 12 Found 8 Missed 4 Current 123 (66% match, 97% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: myshell-0.1-r0 do_package: Fatal errors occurred in subprocesses:
Command '['aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy', '--only-keep-debug', '/home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/myshell/0.1-r0/package/usr/bin/hello_shell', '/home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/myshell/0.1-r0/package/usr/bin/.debug/hello_shell']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Subprocess output:aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/myshell/0.1-r0/package/usr/bin/hello_shell'

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/myshell/0.1-r0/temp/log.do_package.15925
ERROR: Task (/home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/meta-shell/recipes-myshell/myshell/myshell_0.1.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 538 tasks of which 537 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/bhargav/RPI3/Build/meta-shell/recipes-myshell/myshell/myshell_0.1.bb:do_package
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
bhargav@bhargav-Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~/RPI3/Build/poky/build (master)$
```

What mistake am I doing ?

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: I haven't checked it yet. Got caught up in some other work. Will check and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error occurred because you have `CC = gcc` in makefile which points to compiler in `host`. This overrides `CROSS_COMPILER` set by yocto. so the binary you built `hello_shell` is for host (ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64), which throws error while using `aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy`

Try removing `CC = gcc` from makefile

Comment: I commented the `CC = gcc` line in the makefile still I'm getting the error.

Comment: one more point, you can `inherit autotools` & remove do_compile, if you are not going to do anything explicitly while compile. Are you getting same error? even after clean build?

Comment: After removing `do_compile` and  using `inherit autotools` I'm now getting a different error. I think this is related to `makefile` .
Please check the error here : https://pastebin.com/hk3DG90q

Comment: Error say that it could not find ´makefile´ in build directory. Check recipes workdir and makesure that makefile is available. The issue you reported is due to ´CC=GCC´ in makefile, removing that should resolve your do_package issue

Comment: I didn't change the `SRCREV` so I was getting the error

few more observations 
autotools was not able to find the makefile,
after removing it is building successfully

so when are the files compiled with any compile/make command?
here is the snippet of the recipe

https://pastebin.com/tr3Er5Bp

Answer (score 0):

you might need to do following stuff in the .bbappend:

```
inherit externalsrc
inherit autotools

EXTRA_OEMAKE = 'CROSS_COMPILE=${TARGET_PREFIX} CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc ${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}" V=1'
EXTRA_OEMAKE += ' HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC}'
EXTRA_OEMAKE += ' STAGING_INCDIR=${STAGING_INCDIR} STAGING_LIBDIR=${STAGING_LIBDIR}'

do_install_prepend() {
        oe_runmake -C ${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR} mrproper
        oe_runmake -C ${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR} scripts
}
```